# Windows - Make it hard for mouse cursor to move between screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, mouse

I have a dual monitor setup on windows 10.

I would like my mouse cursor to have a minimum velocoty to be able to move to another screen.

Reason: I hate it when I am on the edge of the screen making small movements and the mouse goes to the other screen. I would prefer crossing screens hard, thus only deliberate movements would result in this.